# Releasing keyframes from an action strip in the NLA editor

Tags: nla-editor, actions

I was experimenting with the NLA editor to loop a walk cycle. I've decided I no longer want use the action strip, how do I release my keyframes back into the timeline without losing them?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Keyframes are stored into an "Action", which has a name (Generally the rig name + Action, like "MyCharacterRigAction").

Delete the action strip from NLA, open a Dopesheet Window, turn it to an Action editor, select the rig and choose the Action from its dropdown menu.

[image]